# Google Analytic Goal Flow Number Not Matching

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

The numbers that are shown within a goal flow node do not match the numbers shown in the table below it in the total row.

Could someone please explain why this is or if these numbers represent something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers in the table below are visits.  The numbers in the nodes are pageviews.  Where you get a loop back from one node to another, you'll notice more pageviews than visits (because one visitor has seen the page twice).

Comment: Does a page refresh count as a separate page view aswell?

Comment: It does in the other GA reports - I assume repeated pageviews aren't removed in flow view but I'm not certain.